# Using a join query to retrieve absent data from second table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's consider these two tables:

```
TABLE(T_USER)
  user_id

TABLE(T_MESSAGE)
 msg_type (values = 0, 1, 2, 3)
 answered (values = 0, 1)
 user_id
```

As you can see, there can be `0 - n` message for any user.

I am trying to retrieve, using a SQL query (on *Oracle 10g*), the list of all users for which **no** message of a certain type and not answered exists (i.e. `where msgType = 1 and answered = 0` for example). This user could have others messages, if none of them fulfill these criteria, then my request should

What should this query look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM T_USER u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM T_MESSAGE
                    WHERE user_id = u.user_id
                      AND msgType = 1
                      AND answered = 0)
```

Also want to notice that solution with `NOT EXISTS` will be more performant in oracle than `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your notice, even if in my case the performance is not an issue (the solution with the `left join` is fast enough).

Comment: @romaintaz: even though - in my daily life I prefer not exists since it is slightly more readable for me ;-)

Comment: On my system they all result in exactly the same execution plan and 1893 consistent gets.

Comment: _almost_ exactly the same execution plan ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select u.user_id
    from T_USER u
        left join T_MESSAGE m
            on u.user_id = m.user_id
                and m.msgType = 1
                and m.answered = 0
    where m.user_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea was to put the criteria on the `left join`, not somewhere in the `where` block, like I tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id FROM t_user t where not exists ( select 1 from t_message where user_id = t.user_id and ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE user_id NOT IN 
       (SELECT user_id FROM T_MESSAGE WHERE msgType = 1 AND answered = 0)
```